# React add/remove item to array if checkbox is selected/not selected? (Hooks, not class based component)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I've been looking around different answers but all of them are jQuery related or very complex for what I have in mind?
I am working in a form and want that when user checks a box, its value should be added to an array storing info in the parent component.
If box is unchecked, remove that item from array.

Code trimmed for simplicity

```
const Knowledge = (props) => {
  const checkHandler = (e) => {
    const tools = props.data.usesTools; //Array in parent component
    const value = e.target.value; //Checkbox value
    tools.includes(value) //If Array contains value
      ? tools.filter((tool) => tool.value != value) // Then remove item from Array
      : tools.push(value) // Else, push item to Array;
  };


return (
    <div> 
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkBox"
          name="usesTools"
          value="Slack"
          onChange={checkHandler}
          />
          Slack
      </label>
    </div>
  //Other checkboxes removed for simplicity
 )
}
```

Questions:

1) How to add/remove items to Array if checkbox is selected/not selected.

2) I Tried adding a hook to check/uncheck the box but its checking all the boxes as soon the handler is called:

```
const [ isSelected, setSelected = useState(false);

  <input
    type="checkBox"
    name="usesTools"
    value="Slack"
    onChange={checkHandler}
    checked={isSelected}
  />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you declare a component as a function or a class, it must never modify its own props. React is pretty flexible but it has a single strict rule: All React components must act like pure functions with respect to their props, as you are modifying `props.data.usesTools` in the child component. what you need to do is to pass the callback function in Props to child component which will update the `usesTools` Array, like below

```
## function to update the usesTools state in parent component ##

const [usesTools,setUsesTools]= React.useState([]);
  const updateUsesTools = (item) => {
    if (usesTools.includes(item)) {
      setUsesTools(usesTools.filter(tool => tool.value != item));
    } else {
      setUsesTools([...usesTools, item]);// or push
    }
  };


 ## function in child component to handle change event ##

  const checkHandler = e => {
    const tools = props.data.usesTools; //Array in parent component
    const value = e.target.value; //Checkbox value

    props.updateUsesTools(value);
  };
```

Comment: But data is contained in a big Hook Object like so:
const [datos, setDatos] = useState({
    fullName: "",
    email: "",
    usesTools: [ ],
    //...tons of data more
})

How do I update only usesTools array without touching the rest?

Comment: No issue you can update only usesTools array of object by doing this. setDatos({...datos,usesTools:[...datos.usesTools,newItem]})